# Entity Framework ObjectStateManager not defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a distributed database that I thought might be nice to have events fire on updates so that all users get their data updated immediately and found this nice article; [EF Events](http://romiller.com/2009/06/28/entity-framework-events/)

I'm led to believe from [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424) that the Context is defined as the Entity Container Name, which in my case is "CertsModelContainer"

However, when I try;

```
using (CertsModelContainer db = new CertsModelContainer())
{
    db.ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged | Action: {0}, Object: {1}",
            e.Action,
            e.Element));
    };
}
```

Visual studio informs me that CertsModelContainer does not contain a definition for 'ObjectStateManager'

I'm not sure why this is happening and how to fix it, could someone help me out?
(I'm using EF5 and used ModelFirst to generate my database if that makes any difference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is CertsModelContainer a DbContext or an ObjectContext? Only the latter has an ObjectStateManager.

If you are using transactions you could use Transaction.TransactionCompleted

Comment: I think ModelFirst makes it a DbContext...
Is there any sort of Events similar to what ObjectStateManager has with DbContext?

Comment: You could override SaveChanges and do the work there. Or maybe hook into the transaction completion.

Answer (score 1):

If your CertsModelContainer is a DbContext, you can cast it to an IObjectContextAdapter in order to access the ObjectStateManager.

For example:

```
using (CertsModelContainer db = new CertsModelContainer())
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged | Action: {0}, Object: {1}",
            e.Action,
            e.Element));
    };
}
```